# How does one prove the formula $E[X\mid A] = \frac{E[I_A X]}{P(A)}$

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to find a good way to prove the following formula on conditional expectations:

$E[X\mid A]=\frac{E[I_A X]}{P(A)}$. I am not sure how I would proceed with this. Here $I$ is an indicator of $A$ such that $I\{A\}=1$ if $A$ is true and $I\{A\}=0$ if $A$ is not true.

Comment: How did you define the conditional expectation? With sigma algebras?

Comment: I'm not concerned about sigma algebras, just that A is simply some event. I'm looking to prove this using the properties of conditional expectations and conditioning rather than the concept of sigma algebra.

Comment: For me what you are asking is the **definition**.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You may be able to show

- $E[X \mid A]= E[I_A X \mid A]$
- $E[I_A X] = E[I_A X \mid A] \,P(A)$

and then rearrange, assuming $P(A)>0$

Comment: Thanks! May I ask where does the first equation, $E[X|A]=E[I_{A}X|A]$ follow from? I've been struggling to understand this.

Comment: Apply the Linearity of Expectation: $\mathsf E(X\mid A)~{=\mathsf E((I_A+I_{A^\complement})\,X\mid A)\\=\mathsf E(I_A\,X\mid A)+\mathsf E(I_{A^\complement}\,X\mid A)}$

Comment: Also note that $I_{A^\complement}=0$ when given that event $A$ occurs. @Szemeredi_31

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Szemeredi_31 or notice that whenever $A$ is true you have $I_A=1 \implies X=I_A X$